# How can I get HTTParty to recognize ":footer" and ":collector" parameters?

Tags: ruby, curl, httparty

I received the following code from a development team:

```
curl -u EMAILADDRESS:PASSWORD -d "sender=NAME <EMAILADDRESS>&message=[Invite Link]&collector=COLLECTOR&subject=Test Invite&footer=My Custom Text [Unsubscription Link]"
```

I have been told that the above works fine. This is what I translated it to in Ruby 1.9.3, using the `httparty` gem:

```
call= "/api/v2/emails/?survey=#{i}"    
puts collector_final_id
url= HTTParty.post("https://www.fluidsurveys.com#{call}",
  :basic_auth => auth,
  :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  :collector => collector,
  :body => {
    "subject" => "Test Invite",
    "sender" => "NAME <EMAILADDRESS>",
    "message" => "[Invite Link]"
  },
  :footer => "My Custom Text [Unsubscription Link]"
)
```

Everything within this works fine except for the `:footer` and `:collector` parameters. It doesn't seem to recognize them at all.

There are no errors thrown, they just aren't included in the actual email I am sending. What am I doing wrong when passing in those two parameters?

Comment: There is no comma after your :body parameter

Comment: My apologies - I just left the comma off, it is indeed there in the actual code snippet. I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: The collector value should be "COLLECTOR" not collector . it should be a string

Comment: can you tell me from where you are getting the value for basic_auth ? The value auth dont seem to defined anywhere

Comment: `auth` is defined previously, I just included the code in question. `auth` is working fine. The API call is succeeding, just the two parameters mentioned are not. `COLLECTOR` is a variable defined by the development team, it is equal to `collector` in my code.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code? it's hard to debug without knowing how the variables are being defined

Comment: We can't really help you unless you provide some usable code. Looking at what you've written doesn't help nearly as much as code that can be run, but, unfortunately, yours is missing the definitions of variables. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `:collector` and `:footer` are not correct.

I wrote a little Sinatra service to receive a POST request with any parameters:

```
require 'pp'
require 'sinatra'

post "/*" do
  pp params
end
```

And ran it, launching the web-server on my Mac OS laptop. As Sinatra apps do, it resides at 0.0.0.0:4567.

Running this code:

```
require 'httparty'

url = HTTParty.post(
  "http://localhost:4567/api/v2/emails?survey=1",
  :headers => {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  :body => {
    "subject" => 'subject',
    "sender" => 'sender',
    "message" => 'message',
  },
  :collector => 'collector',
  :footer => 'footer'
)

puts url
```

Outputs:

```
["survey", "1"]["subject", "subject"]["sender", "sender"]["message", "message"]["splat", ["api/v2/emails"]]["captures", ["api/v2/emails"]]
```

Sinatra said:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2013 17:58:47] "POST /api/v2/emails?survey=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0163
{"survey"=>"1",
 "subject"=>"subject",
 "sender"=>"sender",
 "message"=>"message",
 "splat"=>["api/v2/emails"],
 "captures"=>["api/v2/emails"]}
```

Changing `:collector` and `:footer` to strings and moving them inside the body, where they should be:

```
require 'httparty'

url = HTTParty.post(
  "http://localhost:4567/api/v2/emails?survey=1",
  :headers => {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  :body => {
    "subject" => 'subject',
    "sender" => 'sender',
    "message" => 'message',
    'collector' => 'collector',
    'footer' => 'footer'
  },
)

puts url
```

Outputs:

```
["survey", "1"]["subject", "subject"]["sender", "sender"]["message", "message"]["collector", "collector"]["footer", "footer"]["splat", ["api/v2/emails"]]["captures", ["api/v2/emails"]]
```

And Sinatra said:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2013 18:04:13] "POST /api/v2/emails?survey=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0010
{"survey"=>"1",
 "subject"=>"subject",
 "sender"=>"sender",
 "message"=>"message",
 "collector"=>"collector",
 "footer"=>"footer",
 "splat"=>["api/v2/emails"],
 "captures"=>["api/v2/emails"]}
```

The problem is, the POST request ONLY uses a URL and a `:body` hash. Inside the `:body` hash go all the variables you're sending to the server. That's why the second version of the code, with `'collector'` and `'footer'` works.

Comment: Incredible. Thanks for the help, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're new here. If it's exactly what you're looking for, then you should select it as the accepted answer. That's what proper procedure is on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no comma after your `:body` parameter